# C# EF 6.1 - How to know when does the DetectChanges method is called?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, logging

I would like to make some profiling and optimizations in my application and I'd like to see when the method `DetectChanges` is called via Entity Framework itself. I know which methods are supposed to call `DetectChanges`, but I would like to make a simple mechanism which logs or outputs information about such event.

More about DetectChanges method:

- https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/10/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-1-what-does-detectchanges-do/
- http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/5/7/entityframework_performance_and_autodetectchanges

Comment: `DetectChanges` method is overridable. Check [this](https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Internal/InternalContext.cs#L635) out.